# Qt QNetworkReply is always empty

Tags: c++, qt

I want to see the results of a GET request. By my understanding, this code should do it. What am I doing wrong?

```
void getDoc::on_pushButton_2_clicked() 
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com")));
}

void getDoc::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << reply->error(); //prints 0. So it worked. Yay!
    QByteArray data=reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << data; // This is blank / empty
    QString str(data);
    qDebug() << "Contents of the reply: ";
    qDebug() << str; //this is blank or does not print.
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try modifying your replyFinished slot to look like this:

```
QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(bytes.data(), bytes.size());
int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
```

You can then print the statusCode to see if you are getting a 200 response:

```
qDebug() << QVariant(statusCode).toString();
```

If you are getting a 302 response, you are getting a status redirect. You will need to handle it like this:

```
if(statusCode == 302)
{
    QUrl newUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    qDebug() << "redirected from " + replyUrl + " to " + newUrl.toString();
    QNetworkRequest newRequest(newUrl);
    manager->get(newRequest);
    return;
}
```

I'm returning when encountering a status code of 302 since I don't want the rest of the method to execute.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. The qDebug() gives a code of 200, so it works.   
How do I now access the content of the page? And what does
QString xml(str) do?

Comment: Great to hear that it works! I copied the above code from another project of mine and forgot to remove the `QString xml(str)` line. Thanks for bring that to my attention. The `QString str` should give you access to the page content. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: See also QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html), if you use Qt 5.6 <